# android setOnClickListener (v) cannot resolve 'v'

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to android and I am trying to get the listener to work on both the record video and capture picture. It keeps giving me a cannot resolve 'v' error and I am also having trouble in the timestamp, getting it to recognize Date. I have tried switching and enabling different API's 10, 23 and 25. this version of this app is currently running 23 to try to overcome my issues with my listener. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

import java.io.File;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

import static android.R.attr.data;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{    //activity request codes
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;

    //directory name to store captured images and videos
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "Hello Camera";
    private Uri fileUri; //store image video file

    private ImageView imgPreview;
    private VideoView videoPreview;
    private Button btnCapturePicture, btnRecordVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPreview);
        videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
        btnCapturePicture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
        btnRecordVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRecordVideo);

        //capture image button click event
        btnCapturePicture.setOnContextClickListener(View v)
        {
            //capture picture
            captureImage();
        }
            btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(View v)
        {
            RecordVideo();
        }

            if (isDeviceSupportCamera()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Your device doesent support camera",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //will closethe app if the device doesent have camera
                finish();
            }
            }

        }
    //checking device for camera
    private boolean isDeviceSupportCamera()
    {
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(
                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA))
        {
            //THIS DEVICE HAS A CAMERA
            return true;
        } else {
            //no camera on this device
            return false;
        }
    }

    //capturing camera image will launch amera app request image capture
    private void captureImage()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        //start the image capture intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
    // HERE WE store the file uri as it will be null after returning from the app

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(outState);

        //save file uri in bundle as it will be null on screen orientation changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        //get the file uri
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }

    //recording video
    private void RecordVideo()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);
        //set video quality
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        //start the video capture intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    //Recieving activity result method will be called after closing the camera
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {    //IF THE RESULT IS CAPTURING IMAGE
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                //successfully captured the image, displayit in an image view
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {
                //user cancelled Image Capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            if (requestCode == RESULT_OK)
            {   //VIDEO SUCCESSFULLY RECORDED
                //prieview the recorded video
                previewVideo();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)
            {//user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {//failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    //display image from a path to imageView
    private void previewCapturedImage()
    {//hide video preview
        try{
            //hide video preview
            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            //downsizing image as it throws outof memory exception for larger images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            final Bitmap bitmap =        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }

         catch(NullPointerException e)
         {
          e.printStackTrace();
         }
}
// previewing recorded video
private void previewVideo()
{
    try {
        //hide image preview
        imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());
        //start p;aying
        videoPreviewStart();
         } catch (Exception e)
            {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
}

    private void videoPreviewStart()
    {

    }

    //Helper Methods
    //Creating file uri to store image/video
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type)
    {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }
        //returning image/video
        private static File getOutputMediaFile(int type)
{
    //external sdcard location
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
    //create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists())
    {
        if(!mediaStorageDir.mkdir())
        {
            Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
        //Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    if(type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE)
    {
        mediaFile = new File (mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
        + "IMG" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }
        else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO)
    {
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
    return mediaFile;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question so it includes the relevant parts of the code. It is unlikely that anyone here would like to read your whole program. Also, please see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I agree completely with the comment above. Learn from it. I only answered in this case because the problem was immediately obvious. Usually a long post like this is far too unclear.

Comment: maybe you can do a screenshot of the error, maybe it will be better

Answer (score 1):

The problem is these lines:

```
btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(View v) {
    RecordVideo();
}
```

You are passing a value, not creating a method so it should be

```
btnRecordVideo.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
         //you do your actions here
         recordVideo(); //Note: only classes start with capitals, not methods
    }
})
```

You'll also have to change the other lines where you've made similar mistakes